# The text in my date picker shows in the simulator but not when I run it on my ios14 phone

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14

Simulator screenshot
[image: This is the image from the simulator and how it should look]

ios 14 iphone screenshot
[image: This is the screenshot from my phone running ios 14. As you can see there the numbers from the calendar do not show]

Anyone else experiencing this bug?

Comment: More info please! Help us reproduce this by telling us what you're actually doing (in code etc.). Thanks.

Comment: All I did was drag in the date picker and in the code I set the datePicker.prefferedDatePickerStyle = .inline       It works perfectly fine on the simulator. But on my phone I cant see the text. Its really weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `preferredDatePickerStyle`.

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
    }
```

To know more you can check this: https://medium.com/better-programming/introducing-swifts-new-modern-date-picker-37bb5e0a106